# How to access variables in subclasses?

Tags: c#, class, variables, inheritance

Lets say I have three classes, `p`, `p1` and `p2`

```
public class p 
{
  public p() {}
}

public class p_1 : p
{
  public p_1() {}
  public string tester = "ABC";
}

public class p_2 : p
{
  public p_2() {}
  public string foo = "Test";
}
```

Now I want to create a general variable of the type `p` and then use it as type `p_1`. Then I want to access the variable `tester` inside.

```
p p_tester;
p_tester = new p_1();
Console.Writeline(p_1.tester);
```

My question is: Why can't I access the .tester variable? Am I missing something? Visual studio wants me to declare all variables from the subclasses in the main class... but that is not what I want.

Is that what I try to do even possible?

Comment: @Beso you might have misunderstood me. I do not want to access the child class variable from the parent. The last code block is called somewhere else in the program.

Comment: If you want to access members without declaring instances of class you have to declare the member as static. Then you can access from everywhere but the member will have the same values from every object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to cast `p_tester` as `p_1`.
The one thing I'm sure is that you can't access `p_1` directly because your class is not static. You can only access the declared instance `p_tester`

```
p p_tester;
p_tester = new p_1();
Console.WriteLine(((p_1)p_tester).tester);
```

Comment: So if you know what to do, can you tell us ? Say 'This is not correct solution' is just not an answer... Maybe this not correct solution but it works. If you have an array or a list of p, you can add child in it and then have access to members or methods by casting. The same way I can add objects in List<object> without watching the type of objects inside the List. Downcasting and Upcasting are made to work with that.

Comment: As it seems, @Philippe answered correctly for me. Casting ```p_tester``` works fine. But it looks even nicer, if I use ```Console.WriteLine((p_tester as p_1).tester)```.

Comment: ^Keep in mind that casting could fail (when trying to cast to an invalid/non-compatible  type)

Comment: I don't master it but i guess that we can use reflection for dynamic casting.

Comment: [related reading material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)

Answer (score -1):

Your declare function is wrong. Why not access it through the child class?

```
    p_1 p_tester;
    p_tester = new p_1();
    Console.WriteLine(p_tester.tester);
```

If you want to access the tester form child class p_1() then you could set the tester as static variable.

```
    public class p_1 : p
    {
      public p_1() {}
      public static string tester = "ABC";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(p_1.tester);
```

Comment: By using this set-up OP could create a collection typed `p` and add instances of either `p1` and `p2` to the same list. To be less abstract, imagine a `List<Product>` where you could add instances of `Bread`, `Appliance`, `Fruit`, ... (which all derive from `Product`)

Comment: @DarkBee something like this is my intention.

Answer (score -1):

**It seems you actually need an `override` property**

```cs
public class p 
{
  public p() {}
  public virtual string StringValue { get; }
}

public class p_1 : p
{
  public p_1() {}
  public string tester = "ABC";
  public override string StringValue => tester;
}

public class p_2 : p
{
  public p_2() {}
  public string foo = "Test";
  public override string StringValue => foo;
}
```

You can now access it using `p_tester.StringValue`

```cs
p p_tester = new p_1();
Console.Writeline(p_1.StringValue);
```

Comment: How so? What if OP wanted to store like `Rectangle` and `Circle` in a collection, e.g. `List<Shape>`. The circle would have a property `radius` whereas the rectangle does not! Can't imagine you would define all possible properties in the supertype `Shape`? What if OP used an interface `IShape` instead of a parent class and wanted to do the same thing?

Comment: @DarkBee OP has two `string` variables, there is no mention of the properties having supertypes. The simple answer is that if the object is only known to be *some* kind of `p` then you need a (possibly `abstract`) property on the base class, there is no other way without explicitly casting

Comment: This is just a mock-up of OP's situation though